# What gives lower latency, to code business logic in T-SQL or js?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm about to start developing a back-end service for a mobile app using Azure Mobile Services. But I honestly can't figure out which approach is better for perfomance: to code business logic using stored procedures in T-SQL or doing it using javascript. Other than perfomance, also, which one gives more oportunnity to reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript or C# would offer more opportunity for reuse, if for example you later expand your app and need to provide fuller web services than WAMS can provide. In terms of performance there's probably not enough difference to tip the scale one way or the other, since the IO is the main factor.

As a general rule, embedding business/application logic in your database is to be avoided, partly because SQL-derived languages are rarely ideal for that type of code, but more practically because it makes it much harder to support alternative databases in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to use C# in the server for Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it isn't as yet.

Comment: It is now possible to use .NET in WAMS: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/02/20/azure-expressroute-dedicated-networking-web-site-backup-restore-mobile-services-net-support-hadoop-2-2-and-more.aspx